# Abelian group (Commutative group)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if in a group $(ab)^2= a^2 b^2$ then the group is commutative. 
 I am having a hard time doing this. Here is what I have so far: 
Proof: 
 $a^2 b^2= a^1 a^1 b^1 b^1$ 
=$aa^{-1}bb$ 
=ebb 
Hence,$aa^{-1}=e$ 
 I am stuck, I do not know if this is the right process in proving this

Comment: Is $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ for all $a,b$ elements of the group? Or is the group generated by $a,b$ with the relation $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$?

Comment: it is generated by a,b with relation to $(ab)^2=a^2 b^2$

Comment: if only I had a penny for every time this question has been asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$aabb=(ab)^2=abab$ implies that $a^{-1}aabbb^{-1} = a^{-1}ababb^{-1}$. So, $eabe = ebae$. Hence $ab=ba$.

Comment: so I was on the right track? I just got to work with the $(ab)^2$ @Dan Rust

Comment: Well you didn't use the left hand side of the relation that you were given, so you obviously needed to use that somewhere.

Comment: thanks. Im still learning how to properly do proofs.

Comment: Good luck. With a little bit of practice, you see chains of reasoning like above very quickly and naturally.

Comment: one more thing @Dan Rust, the answer you gave me is commutative right? because commutative is usually presented as a + sign

Comment: A group $(G,\bullet)$ is commutative/abelian if for all $a,b\in G$ $a\bullet b = b \bullet a$. Obviously we can ommit the $\bullet$ notation altogether giving $ab=ba$ or, as you suggest, use additive notation with $+$ giving $a+b=b+a$. It's just notation though. We could talk about the integers with addition and write $nm = n+m$ if we really wanted, as long as the reader understood what we meant.